# MVC - Opening an asp.net page from the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't know if this is possible.

Can I have a mvc controller open a popup asp.net page? The asp.net page is within the mvc application, it's basically to run a crystal report viewer.

What happens just now is the mvc view loads and lists reports, then when a report is clicked it launches and exports to pdf. We now want this embedded in a web page instead of exporting to pdf(for various reasons one being no local download of the pdf report).
So sfter reading up i came across the solution to use a folder within the mvc app and use a webform in there. Now I'm trying to find how to open the .aspx pop-up from the controller where the report viewing is initiated.
Does that make any sense.
Any links/help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers in ASP.NET MVC are not supposed to open popups. You could do this using javascript inside the view. The [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) javascript function could be helpful:

```
window.open('/report.aspx', 'report');
```

Comment: Hi, ok thanks I had doubts whether it could be done from the controller.
The problem is, the view queries a db for a list of reports(and their parameters) and then lists the reports as links using 
"str.Append("<input type='submit' name='button' class='clickbuttn' onclick=buttonclick(" + item.ID + ") value='View Report >>'> ");"

this this fires the code in the controller to build the report and export it to pdf. We are trying to find a way to eliminate the export to pdf hence trying to get from these report links, to the reports.aspx page